# JOptimizer - cancel console debug prints

Tags: java, joptimizer

I'm writing a program in Java using JOptimizer for linear programming. Is there a way to cancel all those DEBUG prints of the library to the console?

Answer (score 0):

I troubled with the same problem.
Joptimizer uses log4j to print logs, so put the **log4j.properties** file in your directory. 
If you write "log4j.rootLogger=OFF" in it, all debug logs go away.
And if you use sbt, you should put it in src/main/resources/. It works fine.
I don't know about other cases , but it will work if you put it in an appropriate place.